# "tee" like programming api in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, io

I want to have something like this

```
$> ps -ax | tee -a processes.txt
```

In a UNIX C programming environment, meaning not via shell scripts.

Basically is there a API so that I can tee on STDIN and/or STDOUT so that I can recording automatically anything appears on the CLI down to a file. Imagine there's a foreground process interact with user and response with some output to the terminal. I want to have everything shown in the terminal also in a file for later examination.

I would imagine something as magic as this:

```
tee(STDIN, "append", logFile);
```

Thanks!

Follow-up, this is the program I wrote according to Lars (see Answer section below), but not exactly what I desired:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

        int pfd[2];
        if (pipe(pfd) == -1) { perror("pipe"); }


        if (fork()==0) { // child reads from pipe
                close(pfd[1]);

                mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
                int ufd = open("user_study.log", O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, mode);
                if (ufd == -1) {
                        perror("Cannot open output file"); exit(1);
                } // ++

                char buf;
                while (read(pfd[0], &buf, 1) > 0) {
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1); // write to stdout
                        write(ufd, &buf,1);            //   and to log
                }

                close(pfd[0]);

        } else { // parent write to pipe
                // dup STDOUT to the pipe
                close(pfd[0]);
                dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

                char msg[200];
                msg[0] = "";
                do {
                        scanf("%s", msg);
                        printf("program response..");

                } while (strcmp(msg, "exit")!=0);

                close(pfd[1]);

        }

        return 1;
}
```

Actual running:

```
[feih@machine ~/mytest]$ ./a.out
abc
haha
exit 
program response..   <---- the output is delayed by the chld process, not desired
program response..
program response..

[feih@machine ~/mytest]$ less user_study.log
program response..   <---- the log doesn't contain input
program response..
program response..
```

Desired running and log(simulated):

```
[feih@machine ~/mytest]$ ./a.out
abc
program response..
haha
program response..
exit 
program response..


[feih@machine ~/mytest]$ less user_study.log 
abc
program response..      <--- the log should be the same as the running
haha
program response..
exit 
program response..
```

So up till now, this problem hasn't been fully resolved.

Comment: So you mean that you want every `printf` (etc.) to write data to both `stdout` and to a file?

Comment: The result is the same as what you said. But instead of doing it at the `printf` side, I want to do it at `stdout` side. Kind of like a one time setting since `printf` can be everywhere.

Comment: Can you not have a helper function that you use in place of `printf`?  And have that helper function call `printf` and `fprintf`?

Comment: If you want the log/stdout to contain the input, you need to echo it explicitly. You'll also want to set the parent's stdout buffering to be none (see setbuf).

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement something like [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

- create a pipe (see `pipe(2)`)
- fork
- in the child, read from the pipe and write to each output

  - stdout and a file, or whatever you need
- in the parent, redirect stdout to the pipe (see `dup2(2)`)

There's a bunch of trickiness you need to take care of, but it's doable.

You can't do it this without an extra process, since printf only writes to one file descriptor (the stdout one).

Comment: You could do something similar with a second thread instead of forking but you would have to duplicate stdout first then close it and replace it with the write end of the pipe.

Comment: Lars, I tried your suggestion but it's not exactly what I wanted: